# Git commit in VS Code without any message

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, commit

How do I git commit my changes in VS Code without any message?

In the terminal I used `--allow-empty-message -m ''`. I used to be able to do what I wanted in VS Code by entering one space character, but that is no longer working.

Comment: I had trouble before but couldn't It may only be that I don't know

Comment: please try answer.

Answer (score 1):

Supposing you are using the built-in git client.

You should use the VSCode "TERMINAL" tab with a git aware terminal. It is not possible to do it with the GUI since it forces you to enter a message (that can be empty). Stage your modifications.

Then type in your terminal:

`git commit`

without the `-m` option.

If the git repository expects a message,  an editor window should appear asking you for one.

Answer (score 0):

This works in VS code version 1.64.2.

Open the command pallette (`Ctrl+Shift+P` on PC or `Cmd+Shift+P on a mac`) and type in *commit empty*, select the `Git: Commit Empty` command. A text box will appear to add a commit message.

Comment: The question asks for a commit with no message, not an empty commit with a mandatory message. Your solution still asks for a message, and not providing it will cancel the commit operation.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this on my machine with latest VS Code(1.79.2). I am able to commit by just adding a space in message box.

[image: vs code version details]